# How to run command only on first run playbook, skip on next rerun?

Tags: git, ansible

I want to download data from git only on first run of playbook.
For example, I have this

```
- name: Check if Magento is already installed
  stat: path=/var/www/html/index.php
  register: index_php
- name: Deploy the latest version from OpenMage github, only if it is not already installed
  git:
    repo: 'https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror'
    dest: /var/www/html
    run_once: true 
  when: not index_php.stat.exists
```

Because of some another commands I would run again the same playbook, but without few commands like git.

I tried with register index.php, but afterwards if there is a difference between local and remote repository, I'm getting "msg": "Local modifications exist in repository (force=no)."

Just to mention, I'm very new with Ansible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concept of *run_once* is [to only run a task one time for a batch of hosts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#run-once). This is not what you want, I think.

An option would be to use a [lock file](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch05s09.html). For example:

```
- name: Check Magento lock
  stat:
    path: /var/lock/ansible-magento.lock
  register: lock

- name: Deploy the latest version from OpenMage github
  block:
    - git:
        repo: 'https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror'
        dest: /var/www/html
    - file:
        path: /var/lock/ansible-magento.lock
        state: touch
  when: not lock.stat.exists
```

(not tested)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the "update" option in the git ansible module be worth for you:

Check the [doc page](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/git_module.html?highlight=update).

```
update: no
```

This is the explanation there:

> If ***no***, do not retrieve new revisions from the origin repository
>   Operations like archive will work on the existing (old) repository and
>   might not respond to changes to the options version or remote.

The default is "yes".

Also, check the example in the same doc page:

```
# Example just ensuring the repo checkout exists
- git:
    repo: 'https://foosball.example.org/path/to/repo.git'
    dest: /srv/checkout
    update: no
```

I hope it can help you!

Comment: Hello, thank you, this example works perfectly about this particular problem I mentioned.
But I chose best answerto be from Vladimir Botka, because it is general answer for my question.

Thank you :)